# Visual Studio ( C ) - Printing inf .. how do i get a value?

Tags: c

I'm doing a project for school and after doing calculations, the printed result is always ' inf '. I've done a lot of research and i cannot figure out how to show the value calculated.

Program works likes this:

The user enters the high and low warp factors and the increment value in a specific range. Then the program calculates the velocity from the low warp factor point to the high warp factor point and prints each result to the screen.

velocity calculation for old star trek is v=(w^3)*c
velocity calculation for the new star trek is v=(w^(10/3))*c

v is velocity, w is warp factor and c is the speed of light. these calculations are provided from the school. the variable newV represents the new generation velocity calculation and always shows up as ' inf '.. i'm stuck here and don't know what to do.

Here's the code:

```
double oldV = 0.0;                          
double newV = 0.0;                      
const double c = 299792458.0;   

for (double i = low; i < high; i = i+increment)
{

    oldV = ((pow(low, 3))*c)*3.6;
    newV = pow(low, (10 / (float)3)*c)*3.6;
    low = low + increment;
    printf("%20.2f%20.2lf%20.2a\n", i, oldV, newV);

}//end of calculation for loop
```

I know it's a read but i had to explain, thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: Does the true code include `<math.h> <stdio.h>`?

Comment: What is the code definition of of `increment, low, high`?

Comment: for calculation of newV, you are raising to  c*10/3  . that will yield a very big number ..

Comment: Chux it does include <math.h> <stdio.h> .. On the other note brian helped me solve it.. Now i have to get the math to line up with the sample output

Answer (score 2):

You have the parentheses wrong on this line:

```
newV = pow(low, (10 / (float)3)*c)*3.6;
```

According to the formula given, `c` should be outside of the `pow` function:

```
newV = pow(low, (10 / (float)3))*c*3.6;
```

Comment: Omg i've been trying for hours!! You're eyes helped! It now outputs values of the formula though i'm trying to match the sample output given from the professor and they don't match.. Off by like 100,000. This is a big help thanks!! I guess i needed a fresh pair of eyes!